# ng-flow with Python in the backend

Tags: python, angularjs, image-uploading, flow-js, ng-flow

So it's been a few days and I have been trying to save images to a folder in my web project.

I am using `ng-flow`, and I can reach my python server with a `POST` request

This is what I get in my `request.form`:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('flowFilename', u'glasgow.jpg'), ('flowTotalChunks', u'1'), ('flowRelativePath', u'glasgow.jpg'), ('flowTotalSize', u'634703'), ('flowCurrentChunkSize', u'634703'), ('flowIdentifier', u'634703-glasgowjpg'), ('flowChunkSize', u'1048576'), ('flowChunkNumber', u'1')])
```

and in my `request.files`:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: u'blob' ('application/octet-stream')>)])
```

The main question here is:

**How can I get the image content?**

I am trying to use `PIL.Image` to save the image, but no success so far, since I am not managing to get the image content in the first place.

Thanks! :)

Comment: If you want i had written a python server for flowjs https://github.com/mautrok/pyserver.flowjs take a look at this sample if can help you.